# how to add delay for response of the message in chatbot?

Tags: python, time, chatbot

when I use time.sleep(2) both customer and support message have 2 second delay but I just want to have 2 second delay just for customer.
In this project the customer is bot.

1. This is the chatbot response which extracted from the prediction

```
def chatbot_response(msg):
    ints = predict_class(msg, model)
    res = getResponse(ints, intents)
    return res
```

2. This is the function for sending message and get response

```
def send():
    msg = EntryBox.get("1.0",'end-1c').strip()
    EntryBox.delete("0.0",END)

    if msg != '':
        ChatLog.config(state=NORMAL)
        ChatLog.insert(END, "Support: " + msg + '\n\n')
        ChatLog.config(foreground="#442265", font=("Verdana", 12 ))


        res = chatbot_response(msg)
        time.sleep(2)
        ChatLog.insert(END, "Customer: " + res + '\n\n')

        ChatLog.config(state=DISABLED)
        ChatLog.yview(END)
```

3. create button for sending the message

```
SendButton = Button(base, font=("Verdana",12,'bold'), text="Send", width="12", height=5,
                    bd=0, bg="#D4AF37", activebackground="#D4AF37",fg='#ffffff',
                    command= send )
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean `time.sleep(2)` doesn't work?

Comment: no it doesn't work

Comment: Can you show what you tried and what did not work?

Comment: Where exactly you have added time.sleep(2)?

Comment: I just updated the code

Comment: in the send function after support message

Comment: what happens if you move it to an earlier part in the code? (for instance, immediately after your if statement)

Comment: when I put it after the if for instance just sending message from customer have delay, the bot do not have any delay